# How do you constrain variogram estimates to be a percentage?

Tags: r, variogram, geostatistics

I am interpolating soil texture data with GeoR and ARCGIS. The ordinary kriging process is straight forward and GeoR facilitates cross validation. Has anyone else produced variogram parameters, nugget and/or sill, greater than the range of clay 0-100%? This seems to ruin Kriging variance results. The output variance is greater than the range of observations.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look at the package `compositions`....

Comment: Thanks. Continuing this morning I realized that I can use the log10 of clay to get realistic values.

Comment: It is no surprise that the variance exceeds the range, nor is it meaningful of itself. The variance is a *squared* unit of measure. So, for instance, you could measure clay (with a range of 0 to 100) as a percent and have a variance of 10 percent *squared* yet the same data for clay in parts per million would have a variance of one billion ppm *squared.* If you use a sufficiently small unit of measure, the variance will *always* exceed the range. Also, kriging logs is *quite* different than kriging values, because weighted averages of logs correspond to *geometric* means, not arithmetic means.